# Mockito - wanted but not invoked - interface.method()

Tags: java, junit, mockito, android-testing, verify

I am running a few tests right now in which I mock one of my interfaces like this:

```
interface = mock(InterfaceView.class);
```

I then try to verify one of my methods off of this interface but continually get an error:

```
verify(interface).someMethod(objList);
```

The error I get here is Wanted but not invoked: interface.someMethod(...)
, Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

mockito is actually telling you that your expectation was not met. You implemented your test to expect a call to that method (that's what verify does, unless you parametrize it to verify that never gets called), but your tested instance does not call it with the given parameters.

Answer (score 2):

`verify(interface).someMethod(objList)` It's verification that `someMethod` was invoke exactly one time.

So if there is no interaction, then you shouldn't use this method :D

**Note**:

If You want to verify that object didn't have any interaction, then use:

```
Mockito.verifyZeroInteractions(obj)
```